# Change UIButton background color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

can someone please help me on how to change the button background from white to a different color.
I know how to add an image and make it a custom button, but i don't know how to change the initial button color from white to another color.
Your help will be much appreciated. cheers.

Comment: check http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/

Comment: I'm kinda having a problem here, the color will come only after clicking on the button, any advise please. Thanks .    -(IBAction) nom{
    [[button layer] setCornerRadius:8.0f];
    [[button layer] setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [[button layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
 [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar requirement and did not want to include additional files in my app bundle so  I wrote a two classes which generate button images from RGBA values and add them to UIButton.

Class to create button images:

- https://github.com/bindle/BindleKit/blob/master/BindleKit/views/BKButtonImages.h
- https://github.com/bindle/BindleKit/blob/master/BindleKit/views/BKButtonImages.m

Class to create button with button images:

- https://github.com/bindle/BindleKit/blob/master/BindleKit/views/iOS/BKButton.h
- https://github.com/bindle/BindleKit/blob/master/BindleKit/views/iOS/BKButton.m

If you add the above four files to your project, you should be able to create UIButton with colored backgrounds using the following methods:

```
UIButton * deleteButton = [BKButton redButton];
UIButton * selectButton = [BKButton lightGrayButton];
UIButton * customButton = [BKButton buttonWithRed:0.0 green:0.4 blue:0.37 alpha:1.0];
```